# Pdf Text ARABIC Extraction

Tags: pdf, text, unicode, encoding, fonts

I am trying to make a program which extracts the text from a PDF document
PDF documents contain ARABIC text written by different types of FONT

when I extract the text it works with some files and others not it gives me ambiguous Text

I am using c # and Itext7 to make this program

please show me the methodology to do this with some examples

thank you

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Text extraction from PDFs is problematic and depends on how exactly the PDF was created, not just with Arabic text.

Comment: but I think there would be a solution to minimize the error rate while extracting the text
not necessarily an optimal solution.
there are online services that do this with an acceptable error rate. thank you @ Joachim Sauer